# Getting View in listView item in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, checkbox

I have a listview in a fragment. that listview have a checkbox on each item. I want to set all checkboxes (from sharedpreferences) on fragment start and get all of them on "save" button clicked. save process works currently but load not works.
the code of "save" button OnClickListener:

```
private View.OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                shp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();
                for (int i = 0; i < gridView.getCount(); i++) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) gridView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    editor.putBoolean("" + i, checkBox.isChecked());
                }
                editor.apply();

                editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                if (!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Utils utils = new Utils(getActivity());
                    utils.setName(editText.getText().toString());
                }
                mListener.navigationFragment(new MenuFragment());
            }
        }

    };
```

on this line: `CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) gridView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);` I got checkbox currently and uses `ischecked()` and iterate. I uses this code in load process like this:

```
shp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

for (int i = 0; i < gridView.getCount(); i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) gridView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.setChecked(shp.getBoolean("" + i, true));
}
```

this is like that but `NullPointerExeption` retrieved. I used last code in `onViewCreated`, `onResume` and `onStart` too. any ideas are welcomed.
I must mention to this Button click happens after OnCreateView.

Comment: So it works in the first case but not the second? Is the second definitely called after the adapter and gridview are et up?

Comment: `I have a listview in a fragment. that listview have a checkbox on each item.` - It means you have custom adapter for your listview, if yes, than pass shared preference value to its model and call notifyDatasetChanged() to adapter on fragment's `onResume()`.

Comment: @RobVoisey, Yes just not works in second case. and Yes after initialize and even tested in onResume.

Comment: @user370305 Thank you, but this is not a solution. it's a trick. I am wondering about why nullPointerException happens and I want to know. I think it's because of Fragment (or Activity) lifecycle, because this error not happens in button click after sometime after onCreateView().

Comment: @David - It is a good design pattern and that solve your problem. You have to understand how fragment life cycles works and best strategy to implement your code.

Comment: Actually, What you are doing here is trick. Because you are avoiding android mvc pattern on adapter and data. You are accessing adapter's view in outside of sync process with parentviews.

Comment: @user370305 I fix my issue with your trick. thank you but I don't get more educated.